# Relative and absolute path on Apache localhost

Tags: apache, appserver

I have installed Apache on my local machine (Windows 7, using AppServ).
I opened a library called "MySite" under AppServ directory, so to access it I use the following URL:

```
http://127.0.0.1/MySite
```

The problem is that when I use

```
<link type='text/css' href='/stylesheets/main.css' rel='stylesheet' media='all' />
```

The file is not loaded since it tries to look it in `http://127.0.0.1/` instead of `http://127.0.0.1/MySite` .

How can I change this?

Thanksm

Joel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your apache.conf File and set your DocumentRoot to MySite

Comment: Thanks, but is there any way to change the apache settings so it will act as required?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your question shows a **flaw in your setup**:

You want `http://127.0.0.1/MySite` to point to a certain directory, say `/var/www/MySite`.

This implies that

- `http://127.0.0.1/` points to `/var/www/`, and that
- `http://127.0.0.1/stylesheets` points to `/var/www/stylesheets`.

But you want `http://127.0.0.1/stylesheets` to point to a subdirectory, say `/var/www/MySite/stylesheets.`

It's possible, but probably not very wise.

Workarounds:

- Add an Alias for /stylesheets to `/var/www/MySite/stylesheets`
- Set the DocumentRoot to `/var/www/MySite` and access the site with `http://127.0.0.1`
- vhosts
- Rewrite rules

Answer (score 0):

You could change documentRoot:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#documentroot